# Advice on a 6-terminal, three-phase motor, with two extra wires

Tags: motor, wiring

On the top row of terminals I have w1, v1, and u1 which I get are connected to v2, u2, and w2 on the second row of terminals. Now, on the bottom row of terminals are two wires labeled 3 and 4. Any idea what they are for and how I should connect them?

[image]

Comment: Manufacturer, model number, datasheet? The two extra terminals may be  for a temperature sensor in the motor to prevent overheating. What is the resistance measured between those terminals?

Comment: Hi Uwe, thank you do much for your reply, so would I just connect those two to U2 and W2 ?

Comment: At first you should measure  the resistance between those two terminals.

Comment: Resistance is 1 ohm

Comment: If the resistance is 1 ohm I would guess a thermo switch that will open when temperature of the motor windings is getting to hot. You should use a motor protect unit together with this motor for overcurrent and overtemperature protection. The thermoswitch should be connected to the unit.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a 3 phase, delta-connected motor with thermistor protection against overheating (three series-connected PTC thermistors embedded in the windings and terminated as shown).

[image]

The thermistors would enable a thermistor relay at normal temperature and disable the same at a higher temperature.

The thermistor relay, in turn, would enable / disable the motor power contactor.